# onTouch + canvas + android

Tags: android

I want to draw a circle on the screen, which will move when holding finger. In the code there is a method that changes the color of the screen in this event, but how can I change the position of the circle? poaluysta help!

```
package com.example.canva;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private String sDown;
    private String sMove;
    private String sUp;
    private DrawView dr;
    private Paint p;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        dr = new DrawView(this);
        dr.setOnTouchListener(this);

        setContentView(dr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        x = motionEvent.getX();
        y = motionEvent.getY();

        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
                sDown = "Down: " + x + "," + y;
                sMove = ""; sUp = "";
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
                sMove = "Move: " + x + "," + y;
                dr.changeColor((int)-x);
                dr.getX(x);
                dr.getY(y);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // отпускание
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                sMove = "";
                sUp = "Up: " + x + "," + y;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    }

    class DrawView extends View {
        private Paint p;

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawCircle(getX(),getY(),50,p);
            invalidate();
        }

        public float getX(float X){
            return X;
        }
        public float getY(float Y){
            return Y;
        }

        public void changeColor(int color){
            this.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class DrawView extends View {
        private Paint p;
        int x=getX(),y=getY();
        public void refresh(int x,int y){
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
            invaliate();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawCircle(x,y,50,p);
        }
  }
```

and in onTouch call

```
 dr.refresh(x,y);
```

Also your `getX` and `getY` funcitons are useless

```
   public float getX(float X){
        return X;
    }
```

instead create a variable x in DrawView and setX

```
   public void setX(float X){
        this.X=X;
    }
```

Comment: int x=getX(),y=getY();public void refresh(float x,float y){
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
            invaliate();
        }

Answer (score 0):

`View.getX()` and `View.getY()` were introduced in the API level 11. You should be aware of this. Your DrawView.getX(float X) and DrawView.getY(float Y) are useless since you are returning the same value you are passing to the method. You probably need to call the pair of `View.getX()` and `View.getY()` that are `View.setX(float x)` and `View.setY(float y)` , in the onTouch method. Also those were introduced in the Api level 11.